# Is there any configuration available for Master to divide the load between the slaves in Distributed testing with JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

Is there any configuration available for Master to divide the load between the slaves?

Actually my test has many scripts with odd and even number of threads in it, for e.g. Script_1 = 15 users, Script_2 = 14 users etc.

So it will be difficult to set the number of threads or slaves. Please suggest.

Comment: since it copies the plan from master to any slaves - don't think it's possible as far as I know.  
but you can try this: "use -n to execute JMeter in non-gui mode, -J to pass thread count as a parameter into the test plan, which you can then use as variable inside the test plan, use -R to specify the jmeter slave to be used to execute the test"
that'll require additional dwelling into the test plan to set certain variables.

Comment: But this would not help me to solve my purpose. Is there any wherein master would act as load balancer and it can divide the load may be on the basis of load or round Robbin fashion?

Comment: We can achieve this by keeping script in a "Throughput Controller" and parameterizing "Throughput"  (${vlaue}). Because Jmeter slaves read data from slave "CSV" file only. So we can pass this values from "CSV file", so that we can achieve this.

Comment: Thanks. And is there any way to send the different data files to different slaves?

Answer (score 1):

It is

1. In [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) define "Number of Threads" value using [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function like `${__P(threads,)}`
2. In *user.properties* file (lives under "bin" folder of JMeter installation) on each slave node define "threads" property like:

   - `threads=14` - for slave 1
   - `threads=15` - for slave 2
   - etc.

You can also pass the property via `-J` command line option like:

```
jmeter-server.bat -Jthreads=15
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on different JMeter properties types and ways of setting and overriding them